# How to create an iAd banner that lasts 3 seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I want to create an iAd banner in my app that lasts for 3 seconds and then disappears.

I currently have this in my `RootViewController.mm`.
iAd is connected and is functioning but how do I make it disappear after 3 seconds? I don't need an animation.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

Comment: You won't get paid for it, the banner needs to run for its allotted time (usually 30 seconds from memory). So it's kinda pointless

Comment: iAd will cease to exist this summer.  So it's kinda pointless.

Comment: @Jef do you have a reference to this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `bannerViewDidLoad` delegate method setup a timer to hide the `ADBannerView`.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    myBanner.hidden = NO;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(hideBanner)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO
     ];
}

-(void)hideBanner {
    myBanner.hidden = YES;
}
```

Also, on January 15, 2016 [Apple announced](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a) that the iAd App Network will be discontinued. iAd is scheduled to be discontinued on June 30, 2016 and is no longer accepting new apps into the network.